# How to get character code defined with \let (! Improper alphabetic constant)

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

Here's a example with the "`! Improper alphabetic constant`" error:

```
%% this is ok  
\newcount\mychar
\mychar=\number`a\relax
\showthe a       % shows You can't use `the letter a' after \the
\showthe\mychar  % shows 97

%% this is not ok
\let\Char=a     
\showthe\Char    % shows You can't use `the letter a' after \the
\mychar=\number`\Char\relax  % here error comes
\showthe\mychar
```

Setting the counter should expand till non-expandable token (in this case it's `\relax`). Question: why is `\Char` not expanded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\Char` is not expanded because it is not an expandable token. Unlike `\def\Char{a}` which *expands* to `a` `\let` defines a token that essentially *is* `a` and like `a` it does not expand.

The only way to get hold of this in classic TeX is to take `\meaning\Char` which will be

```
the letter a
```

split that up on spaces, and if the first two words are `the letter` take the letter which will be `a` and then use the `` `a `` syntax as you used.

Look at the source of the `bm` package which does a *lot* of this:-)

---

Working example (plain TeX)

```
\newcount\mychar

\def\zz#1{%
% catcode 11 (letter)
\ifcat a#1%
\expandafter\zza\meaning#1 \relax
\else
%other cases here
-1
\fi}

\def\zza#1 #2 #3 #4\relax{`#3 }

\let\Char=a     



\mychar=\zz{a}
\immediate\write20{a=\the\mychar}

\mychar=\zz{\Char}
\immediate\write20{\Char=\the\mychar}




\bye
```

which produces a log

```
a=97
\Char =97
```

showing the macro accepts explicit or implicit character tokens.

Comment: I knew how to do it with meaning, just wanted to find a simpler solution :) Thanks I accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation with `l3regex`; the number is stored in `\l_linuxss_code_int` for later usage.

One can extend the testing by acting on the search regular expression; this one catches `the letter` or `the character`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getlettercode}{m}
 {
  \linuxss_getlettercode:N #1
  \int_to_arabic:n { \l_linuxss_code_int } % just for testing
 }

\int_new:N \l_linuxss_code_int
\tl_new:N \l_linuxss_meaning_tl
\regex_const:Nn \c_linuxss_search_regex { \A the \s (letter|character) \s }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \linuxss_getlettercode:N #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_linuxss_meaning_tl { \token_to_meaning:N #1 }
  \regex_match:NVTF \c_linuxss_search_regex \l_linuxss_meaning_tl
   {
    \regex_replace_once:NnN \c_linuxss_search_regex { } \l_linuxss_meaning_tl
    \int_set:Nx \l_linuxss_code_int { ` \l_linuxss_meaning_tl }
   }
   {
    \int_set:Nn \l_linuxss_code_int { -1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:NnTF { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_set:Nn { Nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\let\Chara=a
$\getlettercode{\Chara}=\number`a$

\let\Charz=z
$\getlettercode{\Charz}=\number`z$

\let\Charpipe=|
$\getlettercode{\Charpipe}=\number`|$

$\getlettercode{\let}=-1$

\end{document}
```

[image]