# Getting the catcode of a character assigned to a control sequence by \let

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

Given a control sequence `\z` that was defined like `\let\z=z`, how do you get the catcode the character `z` had at the time `\z` was defined?

The obvious solution

```
{\catcode`z=12 \global\let\z=z}
\the\catcode`\z
```

seems to work at the first glance, but it gives the wrong result `11` because `'\z` isn't interpreted as the previously defined control sequence but just another denotation of the character code of the letter `z`.

Using a different control sequence name makes it obvious

```
{\catcode`z=12 \global\let\thez=z}
\the\catcode`\thez
```

when it fails with

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
```

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148303/how-to-get-character-code-defined-with-let-improper-alphabetic-constant) deals with a similar problem, getting the *character* code of such a control sequence, but I don't see a way to use it for this problem as `\meaning` only returns characters of category 12 and 10.

Comment: (In expl3 use `\token_case_catcode`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An implicit character cannot be active, nor it can have catcode 0, 5, 9, 14 or 15. Check each possibility:

```
\def\catcodeofimplicitchar#1{%
  \ifcat\noexpand#1\bgroup 1\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1\egroup 2\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1$3\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1&4\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1##6\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1^7\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1_8\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1 10\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1a11\else
  \ifcat\noexpand#1112\else
  -1\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}

\let\one={ \let\two=} \let\three=$
\let\four=& \let\six=# \let\seven=^
\let\eight=_ \let\eleven=z \let\twelve=0
\begingroup\def\\#1:{\global\let\ten= #1}\\ :\endgroup
\let\thirteen=~

{\tt\meaning\one}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\one

{\tt\meaning\two}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\two

{\tt\meaning\three}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\three

{\tt\meaning\four}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\four

{\tt\meaning\six}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\six

{\tt\meaning\seven}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\seven

{\tt\meaning\eight}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\eight

{\tt\meaning\ten}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\ten

{\tt\meaning\eleven}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\eleven

{\tt\meaning\twelve}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\twelve

{\tt\meaning\empty}:
\catcodeofimplicitchar\empty

\ifnum\catcodeofimplicitchar\one=1 GOOD\else BAD\fi

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I chose this answer because it's more direct and easier to understand

Answer (score 11):

You do want the same general idea as in [How to get character code defined with \let (! Improper alphabetic constant)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148303/how-to-get-character-code-defined-with-let-improper-alphabetic-constant), but you need to use the *text* of the `\meaning`. An example which covers three cases (space, letter, other), and which extends naturally to the other cases:

```
\long\def\getcatcode#1{%
  \expandafter\getcatcodeaux\meaning#1\stop
}
\edef\getcatcodeaux#1\stop{%
  \noexpand\getcatcodespace#1{}{}\detokenize{blank space}\noexpand\stop
  \noexpand\getcatcodeletter#1{}{}\detokenize{the letter}\noexpand\stop
  \noexpand\getcatcodeother#1{}{}\detokenize{the character}\noexpand\stop
}
\edef\temp{%
  \def\noexpand\getcatcodespace##1\detokenize{blank space}##2\noexpand\stop{%
    \noexpand\ifx\relax##1\relax
      10%
    \noexpand\fi
  }%
  \def\noexpand\getcatcodeletter##1\detokenize{the letter}##2\noexpand\stop{%
    \noexpand\ifx\relax##1\relax
      11%
    \noexpand\fi
  }%
  \def\noexpand\getcatcodeother##1\detokenize{the character}##2\noexpand\stop{%
    \noexpand\ifx\relax##1\relax
      12%
    \noexpand\fi
  }%
}
\temp
```

This is all expandable so it can go into the argument of `\catcode` or similar. I've not added any defensive code in case `\z` here is a macro which might contain the test string, a chardef, *etc.*, but one can extend the idea.